# App is crashing with error [Swift._NSContiguousString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, crash, addressbook

App is crashing when i am trying to save contact.

```
private let SharedInsance = AddressBook()

class AddressBook: NSObject {

private let authorizationStatus = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()

private let addressBookRef: ABAddressBook?


class var sharedInsance : AddressBook{
    return SharedInsance
}

override init() {
    addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue()
    super.init()
}


    private func makeAndAddMemberRecord(member: Member) -> String {

    let memberRecord: ABRecordRef = ABPersonCreate().takeRetainedValue()

    if let firstName = member.firstName{
        ABRecordSetValue(memberRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,firstName, nil)
    }

    if let lastName = member.lastName{
        ABRecordSetValue(memberRecord, kABPersonLastNameProperty,lastName, nil)
    }

    if let professionalName = member.professionalName{
        ABRecordSetValue(memberRecord, kABPersonJobTitleProperty,professionalName, nil)
        ABRecordSetValue(memberRecord, kABPersonOrganizationProperty, professionalName, nil)
    }
    if let emailId = member.emailId{

        let emails: ABMutableMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiStringPropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(emails, emailId, kABPersonAnniversaryLabel, nil)
        ABRecordSetValue(memberRecord, kABPersonEmailProperty,emails, nil)
    }

    if let dob = member.dob {
        if dob.doubleValue > 0 {
            let date = Utility.UnixToDate(dob.doubleValue)
            ABRecordSetValue(memberRecord, kABPersonBirthdayProperty, date as CFDateRef, nil)
        }
    }

    if let aniversaryDate = member.aniversaryDate {
        if aniversaryDate.doubleValue > 0 {
            let date = Utility.UnixToDate(aniversaryDate.doubleValue)

            let dates: ABMutableMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiDateTimePropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(dates, date, kABPersonAnniversaryLabel, nil)
            ABRecordSetValue(memberRecord, kABPersonDateProperty, dates, nil)

        }
    }

    //Phone Number
    if let mobileNo = member.mobileNo{
        let phoneNumbers: ABMutableMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiStringPropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, mobileNo, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, nil)
        ABRecordSetValue(memberRecord, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, nil)
    }

    //end Phone Number


    //Address
    let address: ABMutableMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()

    var addressString = ""
    if let address1 = member.address1{
        addressString += " " + address1
    }
    if let address2 = member.address2{
        addressString += " " + address2
    }
    if let address3 = member.address3{
        addressString += " " + address3
    }

    if !addressString.isEmpty{
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, addressString, kABPersonAddressStreetKey, nil)
    }
    if let cityName = member.cityName{
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, cityName, kABPersonAddressCityKey, nil)
    }

    if let stateName = member.stateName{
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, stateName, kABPersonAddressStateKey, nil)
    }

    if let countryName = member.countryName{
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, countryName, kABPersonAddressCountryKey, nil)
    }

    if let zipCode = member.zipCode{
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, zipCode, kABPersonAddressZIPKey, nil)
    }

    ABRecordSetValue(memberRecord, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, nil)


    //end Address

    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBookRef, memberRecord, nil)


    return saveAddressBookChanges()//memberRecord
}

private func saveAddressBookChanges() -> String {
    var status = ""
    if ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges(addressBookRef){
        var err: Unmanaged<CFErrorRef>? = nil
        let savedToAddressBook = ABAddressBookSave(addressBookRef, &err)
        if savedToAddressBook {
            status = "Successully saved changes."
            print("Successully saved changes.")
        } else {
            status = "Couldn't save changes."

            print("Couldn't save changes.")
        }
    } else {
        status = "No changes occurred."
        print("No changes occurred.")
    }

    return status
}
}
```

[image: CRASH SCREEN SHOT]

```
2015-12-31 12:24:44.500 KGA[2939:75016] -[Swift._NSContiguousString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb1b2f1b740

2015-12-31 12:25:01.316 KGA[2939:75016] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._NSContiguousString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb1b2f1b740'

*** First throw call stack:

(

    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107066f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165

    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106454deb objc_exception_throw + 48

    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010706f56d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205

    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106fbceea ___forwarding___ + 970

    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106fbca98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120

    5   AddressBook                         0x00000001053f3622 ABCDBContextSaveMultiValue + 1446

    6   AppSupport                          0x000000010d12beb3 CPRecordStoreSaveRecord + 1399

    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106f5e446 __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke + 22

    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106f5e400 CFBasicHashApply + 128

    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106f5e33a CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 186

    10  AppSupport                          0x000000010d12ceae _CPRecordStoreSaveAddedRecords + 76

    11  AppSupport                          0x000000010d12cc85 CPRecordStoreSaveWithPreAndPostCallbacksAndTransactionType + 313

    12  AddressBook                         0x00000001053e438d ABCAddressBookSaveWithConflictPolicy + 1751

    13  AddressBook                         0x00000001053fce3e ABAddressBookSave + 84

    14  KGA                                 0x00000001049f10f2 _TFC3KGA11AddressBookP33_19518E706057D2CD55E2EE9EBB4CCBB622saveAddressBookChangesfS0_FT_SS + 178

    15  KGA                                 0x00000001049f0fd1 _TFC3KGA11AddressBookP33_19518E706057D2CD55E2EE9EBB4CCBB622makeAndAddMemberRecordfS0_FCS_6MemberSS + 6113

    16  KGA                                 0x00000001049ee751 _TFC3KGA11AddressBookP33_19518E706057D2CD55E2EE9EBB4CCBB619addMemberToContactsfS0_FCS_6MemberT_ + 225

    17  KGA                                 0x00000001049f3b9b _TFFFC3KGA11AddressBook33promptForAddressBookRequestAccessFS0_FGSQCS_6Member_T_U_FTSbGSQCSo7CFError__T_U_FT_T_ + 603

    18  KGA                                 0x00000001048e0af7 _TTRXFo__dT__XFdCb__dT__ + 39

    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109982e5d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12

    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001099a349b _dispatch_client_callout + 8

    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010998b2af _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738

    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106fc72e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9

    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106f888a9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073

    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106f87e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488

    25  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b209ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161

    26  UIKit                               0x00000001078b230d UIApplicationMain + 171

    27  KGA   
                              0x000000010493004d main + 109
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001099d892d start + 1

)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Can you post the error or stack trace?

Comment: please check i have update my question

Comment: How is `addressBookRef` declared?